# Why is the Japanese word for "this year" not kyōnen or konnen but kotoshi?

Tags: readings, reading-comprehension

I was testing myself on dates/times today and failed to get the reading right for "this year" (今年) based on the kanji. I had reasonably expected that "this year" might be read as kyōnen as it sounded like a valid word and made sense logically (i.e. "this year" or "the year that is happening now") yet I find that kotoshi is the correct word.

What I would like to know is why the kanji is read as kotoshi as it isn't obvious (to me) from just looking at the kanji. I didn't know that the kunyomi reading for 年 was "toshi", but in order for this to work the onyomi reading for 今 has to be "ko" rather than "kyō" or "kon" as I expected. I just want to know what the logic is behind this so that I can remember it properly. Is the "ko" reading used in any other date/time-related kanji?

Also, I have read online that kotoshi is a noun as well as an adverb. How would kotoshi be used as an adverb in a sentence?

Thank you for any input/comments or examples.

Comment: "こんねん" isn't wrong: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BB%8A%E5%B9%B4_%28%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AD%E3%82%93%29/#jn-83911

Comment: Also "kyo" isn't a regular reading for 今, it's a special reading for the word 今日 called 熟字訓 (jukujikun): https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%86%9F%E5%AD%97%E8%A8%93 and https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanji/113.html

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Do you know if there is any reason to use こんねん in preference to ことし?

Comment: Formality. https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/12825/meaning/m0u/ and https://ja.hinative.com/questions/18752568. If you must be formal, prefer using 本年 (ほんねん) though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*ko* (from older **kə*) is native Japonic ancient proximal demonstrative pronoun ("this"), now surviving as prefix. Rarely used kanji spelling for this prefix is 此.

Some words with this prefix:

- *kore* ([此]{こ}れ) "this"
- *kono* ([此]{こ}の) "this"
- *konna* ([此様]{こん}な) "this kind", contraction of [此]{こ}の[様]{よう}な
- *koko* ([此処]{ここ}) "this place"
- *kotabi* ([此]{こ​}[度]{​たび}) "this time"
- *kotosi* ([今年]{ことし}) "this year"
- *kyō* ([今日]{きょう}) "this day"

  Word meaning "this day" developed in this way:

  */kʲe/ + */pu/ → */kʲepu/ → /kepu/ → /keu/ → /kʲoː/

  */kʲe/ was apophonic form of */kə/ "this".

  */pu/ was apophonic form of */pi/ "day".
- *kesa* ([今朝]{け​さ}) "this morning"

  Word meaning "this morning" developed in this way:

  */kʲe/ + */asa/ → */kʲesa/ → /kesa/

  */kʲe/ was apophonic form of */kə/ "this".

  When 2 [consecutive vowels would occur in one word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese#Morphophonemics) (in this case */ʲea/), in most cases, vowels would fuse or one vowel would be elided (here initial */a/ from */asa/).
- *koyoi* ([今宵]{こよい}) "this evening"

  <sub>(Phonological developments and phonemic realizations according to Frellesvig (2010))</sub>

---

Usage of kanji 今 "now" instead of kanji 此 "this" for words 今年, 今日, 今朝 and 今宵 are examples of [[熟]{じゅく}[字]{じ}​[訓]{くん}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#Special_readings), i.e. kanji used for meaning but not reading.

---

今年, 今日 and 今朝 also have regular Sino-Japanese *on'yomi* readings, こ​んねん, こ​んにち and こんちょう.

---

Kanji 今 has only *on'yomi* こん and きん and *kun'yomi* いま, so there is no reason for any *kyōnen* (きょうねん) reading of word 今年.

There happens to exist similarly sounding word *kyonen* ([去]{きょ}[年]{ねん}, with short /o/), which means "last year".

---

Some more information about **kə* in Old Japanese:

Alexander Vovin (2020, "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese", "Chapter 4 Nominals, Section 2.4.1.1.1.1 Isolated Form *kǝ*", pages 263-264):

> 2.4.1.1.1.1 Isolated Form *kǝ*
>
> Isolated form *kǝ* is attested in Western Old Japanese in three examples in the *Kojiki kayō* with the following particles, and once in the *Nihonshoki kayō*, modifying the following noun *yǝpi* ‘night.’ Both usages survived into Classical Japanese, but there they become even more infrequent. In modern Japanese this isolated form survived only in compounds like *kotosi* ‘this year’ (OJ *kǝ tǝsi*).
>
> **許**母布佐波受
>
> ***kǝ** mǝ pusap-a<sup>n</sup>z-u*
>
> **this** FP be suitable-NEG-FIN
>
> **This** is not suitable, either (KK 4)
>
> **許**斯與呂志
>
> ***kǝ** si yǝrǝsi*
>
> **this** EP be good
>
> **this** is good (KK 4)
>
> **許**斯母阿夜爾加志古志
>
> ***kǝ** si mǝ aya n-i kasiko-si*
>
> **this** EP FP very DV-CONV be awesome-FIN
>
> **This** is very awesome, too (KK 100)
>
> 区茂能於虚奈比**虚予比**辞流辞毛
>
> *kumo-nǝ okǝnap-i **kǝ yǝpi** siru-si mo*
>
> spider-GEN perform-NML **this night** be distinctive-FIN EP
>
> the spider’s performance is distinctive **tonight** (NK 65)
>
> In this example *kǝ* has a modifier function without the following *n-ǝ*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and examples. Yet again I realise how little I know about the language. I don't think I've ever seen "kore" written as 此れ but as you say that's probably to be expected. Thanks again. Seeing how the kanji is used and how the words have been contracted/simplified over time is also very helpful.

Comment: 「こんちょう」だけは聞いたことすらありませんね。

Comment: Why don't 今週, 今月, 今夜 etc. follow the same pattern, and end up with a pronunciation lacking the ん?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel As you can see in quoted text, standalone *kǝ* ~ *ko* (MJ *ko*) was slowly dying out. *kǝ yǝpi* ~ *ko yopi* is attested. I doubt that there were weeks before introduction of gregorian calendar in Japan. Presumably something like *kǝ tukɨ* ~ *ko tukwi* (MJ *ko tuki*) could have been also spoken, but is not attested in Old Japanese texts. Linguistics is more often able to find answers to **what** and **when** changed, than **why**. Perhaps *kǝnǝ tukɨ* ~ *kono tukwi* (MJ *kono tuki*) phrase was sufficient. (Here, ~ separates reconstructions by Vovin and Frellesvig for Old Japanese.)

Comment: Isn't that the origin of 今宵?

Comment: @aguijonazo Yes, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/今宵#Japanese) agrees that 今宵 is modern kanji spelling for this word.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have seen "kore" written as 此れ, but only when the writer is actively trying to look/sound archaic (or the text really is that old). Not unlike when an English speaker uses "thou".

Comment: I have also many times seen その written as 其の (preceding a number) when it is used in part/chapter/episode meaning (e.g. 其の一, 其の二). (Usual kanji for *ko-*, *so-*, *(k)a-* demonstrative pronouns are 此, 其, 彼 respectively.)